# Why does this recursive function skip numbers?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to find the various possibilities to equal 100 with digits 1-9. This function produces the desired results, but also others which I had not intended. The other results add up to 100, but without some of these digits, like leaving out 3 or 6. Why are these other results included?

```
    var nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    var signs = ["+", "-", "N"];
    var results = [];
    find100("1");
    function find100(expr) {
       if (eval(expr.replace(/N/g, "")) === 100) {
          results.push(expr);
       } else {
          for (var i = eval(expr.substring(expr.length - 1, expr.length)) + 1; i <=    
          nums.length; i++) {
             signs.forEach(function(sign) {
                var expr2 = expr;
                find100(expr2 += sign + i);
             });
          }
       }
    }
```

Desired output:

```
1+2+3-4+5+6+78+9, 
1+2+34-5+67-8+9, 
1+23-4+5+6+78-9, 
1+23-4+56+7+8+9, 
12+3+4+5-6-7+89, 
12+3-4+5+67+8+9, 
12-3-4+5-6+7+89, 
123+4-5+67-89, 
123+45-67+8-9, 
123-4-5-6-7+8-9, 
123-45-67+89
```

Comment: eval()? why are you using eval? that's almost always a sign of horrible bad design.

Comment: Can you include what your output is and which values you were or were not expecting?

Comment: Because I'm building a string with either +, -, or nothing (N), which will later be evaluated

Comment: Each digit should occur *exactly* once?

Comment: Keep in mind just having eval in a javascript runtime will put the jsvm into a mode where it cannot do a lot of optimizations and is considered generally bad practice.

Comment: Undesired ouput includes (I can't include everything, exceeds max): 1+2+34-5+68, 1+2+34-6+78-9, 1+2+3+5+89, 1+2-3+4+7+89. Yes, each digit should occur exactly once.

Comment: Do the digits have to be considered in different order as well, or should they stay in order, like in your examples?

Comment: Eval is appropriate here, contrary to popular, zombie, contrarianism. Would you care to be specific as to why it wouldn't be?

Comment: The digits should stay in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's adding undesired results because your first loop iterates through each of the remaining numbers and adds ANY results that evaluate to 100, even if it has skipped a number to do so.  If the method finds a solution for a number it adds the solution to `results` - which is correct, however if it doesn't find a solution it moves onto the next number anyway. This is the source of the skipped numbers. If there was no solution for a number it should have not continued to the next number.

As to how to fix it, that's a different question (but why not ...)

The difference here is that you can ONLY get a result if for any number there exists an expression that uses all remaining numbers.

```js
var results = [];
var operations = [ "+", "-", "" ];
var expected = 100;
var limit = 10;

function findExpression(expr, next) {
    if (next === limit) {
        eval(expr) === expected && results.push(expr);
    } else {
        operations.forEach(function(operation) {
            findExpression(expr + operation + next, next + 1);
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    findExpression("1", 2);
    for(var i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
        $("#foo").append(results[i]+"<br />");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="foo"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: But why does it skip a number to do so?

Comment: Because of your for loop.  Your code starts at 1 then iterates through every number remaining.  If it finds a solution for 2 it adds it - which is fine, but if it doesn't find a solution for 2 it moves on to 3 anyway.  There's where your problem is coming from.  If there was no solution for 2 it should have stopped.

Comment: @Gragh Because it's a for loop?  Sorry for sounding trite, but if you don't tell the for loop to break, it's just going to continue onto the next number.  It should have stopped because if it can't find a solution by appending the current number to the existing partial expression none of the subsequent expressions would be valid

Comment: @Gragh I suspect you should really do findExpression("", 1) because your result set is missing this: `-1+2-3+4+5+6+78+9`.  Only problem is you're going to get repeats since `+1+2+3-4+5+6+78+9` and `1+2+3-4+5+6+78+9` are technically different

Comment: It should only start with a positive one. I also can't get your solution working, for some reason.

Comment: might be your version of jQuery?  Although since all jQuery is being used for is `$(document).ready` and appending to a div it's massive overkill.  Also, I've done a few edits, maybe you got it 1/2 way through or something.

Comment: @Gragh yes, but you should check it's up to date.  I just keep whatever version was already in my scratch pad.  I don't really know how to help any further - since it's working in the snippet the assumption would be there's something going on in your environment that's the issue

Comment: Sorry, that was my own stupidity in not including it between script tags.

Comment: @Gragh so it worked out?  Got your question answered?

Answer (score 1):

The reason that some digits are skipped is in this loop:

```
for (var i = eval(expr.substring(expr.length - 1, expr.length)) + 1; i <=    
      nums.length; i++) {
```

On the second iteration it will increment that last digit in the expression, which will therefore create a gap in the continued recursion. In short, that loop should not be there.

I would suggest a solution without using `eval`, not because it would be somehow dangerous, but because it is responsible for a major performance hit.

Instead you could keep a numerical variable updated to what the expression represents. In fact, I suggest to use two such variables, one for the sum of the previous terms, and another for the last term, because that one might need to still be extended with more digits.

To facilitate the different way the signs influence the expression, I have defined a function per sign: it takes the above mentioned numerical values, and also the last digit, and returns the updated values.

Here is a working snippet (ES6 syntax) using that idea, and you'll notice the dramatic performance improvement:

```js
function find100(digits, signs) {
    const loop = (expr, i, [sum, value]) =>
        // Not yet all digits used?
        i < digits.length ?
            // Apply each of the signs in turn:
            Object.keys(signs).reduce( (results, sign) =>
                // Recurse, passing on the modified expression, the sum of the 
                // preceding terms, and the value of the last term. As '+' is
                // not any different than '' before the first digit, skip '+':
                sign != '+' || i ?
                    results.concat(loop(expr+sign+digits[i], i+1, 
                                        signs[sign](sum, value, digits[i]))) :
                    results,
                [] ) :
        // All digits were used. Did it match?
        sum+value == 100 ? [expr] : [];
    // Start recursion
    return loop('', 0, [0, 0]); 
}

var nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
// define how each sign should modify the expression value:
var signs = {
    '+': (sum, value, digit) => [sum+value, digit],
    '-': (sum, value, digit) => [sum+value, -digit],
    '' : (sum, value, digit) => [sum, value*10 + (value<0 ? -digit : digit)]
};
var results = find100(nums, signs);

console.log(results);
```

Note that this also outputs the following expression:

```
-1+2-3+4+5+6+78+9
```

This is because the code also tries the signs before the first digit. I thought it would be relevant to have this also included in the output.